How to Track Export Actions Per User with WPDataTables Plugin in WordPress?
I'm currently evaluating the WPDataTables plugin for a WordPress project. Specifically, I need to track how many times each user exports data from a table. This functionality is critical for our project as we need to limit how much data our subscribers can export to prevent database scraping.
Does the WPDataTables plugin offer a built-in feature to count export actions per user? If not, is there a recommended approach or workaround to implement this functionality?
Thank you for your help!:)
——
I reviewed the WPDataTables documentation and explored the plugin settings but couldn't find an option to count export actions per user. I was expecting to find a built-in feature or a setting to track user-specific export activity.

We can use workaround approach to achieve the required functionality. In this approach we will use WordPress's user meta to track the export actions per user.
Whenever the export button is clicked, we will increment a counter stored in the user's meta data in order to track user.
Step 1: Here we need to add custom JavaScript to theme JS file to detect clicks on the export button and send an AJAX request to the server. In this '#table_1_wrapper' is the table id.
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var ajaxurl = 'https://gomarketish.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'; // Replace with your actual AJAX URL

    $('#table_1_wrapper').on('click', '.buttons-csv, .buttons-excel, .buttons-pdf', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'track_export_action'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Export action has been tracked.');

                // Check if response is a string and equals to 'You have reached your max. export limit.'
                if (typeof response === 'string' && response.trim() === 'You have reached your max. export limit.') {
                    // Hide buttons with class 'DTTT_button_export'
                    $('.DTTT_button_export').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

Step 2: Here we are adding a custom function in your theme's functions.php file to handle the AJAX request and update the user meta.
function track_user_export_action() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $export_count = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'export_count', true );

        if (!$export_count) {
            $export_count = 0;
        }

        $export_count++;
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'export_count', $export_count );

        wp_send_json_success( 'Export action tracked' );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error( 'User not logged in' );
    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_track_export_action', 'track_user_export_action' );

Step 3: Here we need to add a check to see if the user has exceeded their export limit before allowing the export action. This also needs to add to your theme's functions.php file.
function set_limit_export_actions() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user_id      = get_current_user_id();
        $export_count = get_user_meta($user_id, 'export_count', true);
        $max_exports  = 10; // Set your limit here

        if ($export_count >= $max_exports) {
            wp_die( 'You have reached your max. export limit.' );
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_track_export_action', 'set_limit_export_actions', 1);

Please let me know if this helps.

Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I've tried refreshing the site before and after exporting, as well as using different tables, but the export doesn't lock after reaching the limit I've set.
To provide more details, I've inserted the code from the first step into the Hello-frontend.js file (https://imgur.com/a/hsNYDLT), and steps 2 and 3 into the functions.php file (https://imgur.com/a/akmj2vW).
Thank you, Narendra:)
Mia

Could you please share the website URL so I can take a more closer look

Sure thing! (https://gomarketish.com/). You can just register, and then you can see the datatable.

I have checked and found that https://gomarketish.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/assets/js/hello-frontend.js is not enqueue in the website so please add the code to https://gomarketish.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/assets/js/hello-frontend.min.js which is enqueued in the website, also I have updated the code I have mentioned in step 1 as per the class of data table so please update the same at your end.
Screenshot : https://ibb.co/cvQ6zNX

I implemented the new code from the first step you provided into the https://gomarketish.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/assets/js/hello-frontend.min.js for the trial dashboard. Unfortunately, it still doesn't lock the export option after 10 exports...

The code is not working because of it's wrong id so please made the following changes.

Please replace #table_11_wrapper with #table_1_wrapper in the JS code (also highlighted in the screenshot).

https://ibb.co/LgDHd54

I initially thought the ID referred to the table ID within wpdatatables, so I updated it to 11. However, despite this change, the export function still isn't locking after reaching the limit. Could you please take a look at it? I really appreciate your assistance, Narendra!:)

It is showing in the network tab please find the screenshot. https://ibb.co/P1fHB5Z

Thank you for your help! I checked the Network tab and I see the AJAX request being made as shown in your screenshot, which confirms that the tracking is working. However, I noticed that users can still export data even after they exceed the limit I've set.
How can we prevent further exports once the user has reached their maximum limit? Is there an additional step we need to take to enforce this restriction in the frontend or backend? Thank you:)

I have updated the code in Step 1, please update at your end, it should work.

I can't thank you enough for your help, Narendra. It's working on Microsoft Edge now, but I'm experiencing some issues on Google Chrome. I'll do some troubleshooting to see if I can resolve it. I'll text you in some time if I will be able to do it:)

Narendra, I have been trying to figure it out, but I wasn't able to find where the issue lies due to my coding skills:D It works perfectly on Microsoft Edge, but on Google Chrome, it shows an issue on my side (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - hello-frontend.min.js:92). Could you please take a look at it, Narendra?

It is working fine at my end in Google Chrome too please find the attached video link.
https://streamable.com/0nh9x7

Oh, I see, that's quite interesting. I've tested it on multiple devices, including Safari on iPhone, and it only works in Microsoft Edge. My last question: is it possible to integrate the counting with a monthly reset within an Elementor widget or some part of the dashboard? This way, users can easily see if they are near their limit, and it might help us pinpoint whether the issue is with the counting or with hiding the export button. Thank you again, I don’t know what would I have done without your help, Narendra.

Please add the given code in functions.php file to show export count in Dashboard widget.
`add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'dashboard_widgets_for_export_count' );
function dashboard_widgets_for_export_count() {
wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'export_count_widget_user_dashboard', 'Export Count', 'dashboard_export_count_widget' );
}
function dashboard_export_count_widget() {
$user_id      = get_current_user_id();
$export_count = get_user_meta($user_id, 'export_count', true);
echo 'Your export count is : ' . intval( $export_count ) . '';
}
`

Wow, it's working perfectly now. How did you learn all of that? Even the WPDataTables support said this isn't possible due to their plugin limitations, and you just did it. Thank you very much. Is there a way I could do a favor for you too? It means a lot to me!

I am noteworthy WordPress Developer. If you want we can connect through social media profiles where we can discuss more.

Also you can mark this question resolved if your queries has been resolved.

Alright, I will do that. Thank you!... btw I texted you on instagram;)
